# Scanning @Configuration beans in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Hy

I am upgrading my web app from Spring 3.1 to 4.1.8 but having issues. My code has not changed (only my pom.xml)

I have a configuration bean in my main context that looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class StorableServiceConfiguration {
    ...
    @Bean 
    public StorableService<Template, Long> templateService(ITemplateJpaDao dao) {
        return new DaoService<Template, Long>(Template.class, dao);
    }
}
```

And obviously somewhere else in my web app, I have this statement:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("templateService")
private StorableService<Template, String> templateService;
```

Now this all worked fine with Spring 3.1.1 but after updating the version to 4.1.8, I am getting this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [w.wexpense.service.StorableService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=templateService)}

Anybody got a clue?

I read somewhere that there was a change in Spring 4 on how the context:component-scan behave regarding the @Configuration annotation but can't remember what. Is anybody aware of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 4 *autowire* beans using Java generics as form of `@Qualifier`.

So you have a Bean `@Autowired` with `StorableService<Template, String>` but in your `@Configuration` class your `@Bean` declares `StorableService<Template, Long>`.

If you want a `StorableService<Template, String>` instance you should create another `@Bean` at your `@Configuration` class, for example:

```
@Bean 
public StorableService<Template, String> templateService(ITemplateJpaDao dao) {
    return new DaoService<Template, String>(Template.class, dao);
}
```

and *autowire* it without the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Autowired
private StorableService<Template, String> templateService;
```

Spring 4 will inject it perfectly. Look at this blog [post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) to see this new feature of Spring 4.

Comment: Gee thanks a lot, I missed that one; And it actually did the trick... change it to long and run smoothly